# Attach a trait to a class object request by a condition

Tags: laravel

Does anyone know if it is possible in Laravel to attach a trait to a class object request by a condition like eloquent when()?

```
$object-> ... like ... ->when(condition, function($query) { return $query->trait();}) ...
```

Comment: Why not use a condition in the trait?

Comment: because trait in one of the composer dependencies